# CSS before and float on different elements work together

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to `:hover` a picture and then showing a `:before` on an other element (h2) how can I do this?

Comment: Show your code please!

Comment: We have to see the portion of your html code, otherwise your question will be closed for "off topic" reason.

Comment: The literal answer would be 'not possible with just CSS', but there may be a work-around if we could see your actual markup. It's important to know if the H2 is in any relation with the image or if they are far apart in the document.

Comment: there is no relation

Comment: `<h2>Aka Hisfantor</h2>
    
  </header>
  <ul class="profile-social-links">
    
    <!-- twitter - el clásico  -->
    <li>
      <a href="http://twitter.com/tutsplus">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/social-twitter.svg">
      </a>
    </li>`

Answer (score 0):

If you have both the elements laid out as siblings, you can show them using the sibling selector `+`:

```css
img:hover + h2:before {display: block; width: 100%; height: 2px; background: #f00; content: ' ';}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />
<h2>Image</h2>
```

---

The above solution works only if the elements are adjacent or somehow related, as CSS cannot use parent selector (which is possible in CSS 4 specification). But this can be achieved easily using jQuery:

```
$("img").mouseover(function () {
  $("h2:before").css("display", "block");
});
```

Comment: no sry they are one very different parts of the html-tree

Comment: Nopes, then it is not possible with CSS. JS might come handy.